# Create a Custom History in Django showing specific field changes

Tags: python, django, field, history, django-simple-history

Heyho,

in Django i want to create a history view of my model 'application' which shows a table with the columns: Who (changed), When, which field, old Value, new Value

I found the [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) app which stores every version of a model instance in a new model. Actually excactly what i need, but i do not know, how to get the fields of a historical object and especially just the fields which changed comparing two sequenced historical objects.

Has anybody an idea or maybe a complete new approach for that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this in a project of my own. Take a look at [this](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history_diffing.html) part of the docs. The basic idea is is you diff all of the historical records to each other and then loop over each diff to see the individual field changes. If you do it right, you should be able to construct something that looks like this:

```
July 24th, 2018:
    Field | Initial value | New value
    ---------------------------------
    Name  | "Bob"         | "Bobby"
    bool  | True          | False
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the date from `delta.changes`? It only contains `field`, `old`, `new`. I'm trying to achieve a similar result but cannot figure out how to access the history fields such as `changed_by` and `history_date` when iterating over `delta.changes`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things you may consider:

> 1. Create a new model and connect the history table as a foreign key, It will be a one to one relations.
> 2. Now, you have to make a function to detect which fields got changed by comparing every two fields.

If I face the same issue I would go as above. 
However, if you already got the solution in this meantime, please share. Thanks.